# Manipular ArrayList desde diferentes clases

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo 3 clases(VENTANA1,VENTANA2,LISTAS)
En la clase "VENTANA1" instanciaré la clase "LISTAS" y llenaré desde un método un ArrayList.

Cómo puedo recorrer ese ArrayList desde VENTANA2?

Según yo entiendo, desde Ventana 1 creo un objeto de la clase listas, llenando desde ese objeto el ArrayList.

Y cuando yo quiero recorrer desde Ventana2 el ArrayList, no me lo permite ya que son 2 objetos diferentes.

Clase principal que instancia el llenado y el recorrido del array.

```
package menu;

public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu1 m1 = new Menu1();
        Menu2 m2 = new Menu2();

        m2.Llenado();
        m1.Recorrido();

    }

}
```

En ésta clase tengo la creación del Array y dos métodos los cuales permiten llenar la lista y el otro recorrerla.

```
package menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Listas {

    ArrayList<String> lista;

    public Listas() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String LlenarLista(String data) {
        lista.add(data);
        return data;
    }

    public void Recorrer() {
        for (String res : lista) {
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

}
```

Clase que instancia Lista y llena el Array con el método

```
package menu;

public class Menu2 {

    Listas lista;


    public Menu2() {
        lista = new Listas();
    }

    public void Llenado(){
        String info = "Hola mundo";
        lista.LlenarLista(info);
    }



}
```

Clase que instancia a Lista y recorre el Array

```
package menu;

public class Menu1 {

    Listas listas;

    public Menu1() {
        listas = new Listas();
    }

    public void Recorrido() {
        listas.Recorrer();
    }

}
```

Sé que ésto no funcionará porque las dos clases instancian objetos diferentes.

"Desde el Menu2 tengo que llenar el Array y desde el Menu1 debo recorrerlo"

Comment: La ventana2 se genera a partir de la ventana1? Se crea antes o después de generar el array? Tienes algún método para acceder a él desde ventana2? Por favor, explica un poco mejor el funcionamiento de tu aplicación y pon el código correspondiente a esto

Comment: Son dos JFrames independientes el uno del otro, la ventana2 se crea después de llenar el ArrayList. Pondría el código pero sería eterno

Comment: Pon solo la parte relevante: cómo se crean las listas y cómo se comunican las clases entre sí para manipular dichas listas.

Comment: Tienes que poner el código. Pero crear una instancia de una clase y pasarle datos a la otra mediante getters debe ser la solución

Comment: Edité la publicación y añadí el código respectivo :)

Comment: Se puede hacer muy fácil. Lo que no entiendo es qué sentido tiene aquí usar una clase para llenar y otra para recorrer, cuando puedes usar la clase `Listas` para ambas cosas.

Comment: En mí programa tengo 2 JFrames independientes. Uno que añadiría al ArrayList y el otro que lo recorrería

Comment: Deja la lista `static` y accede desde cualquier clase.

Comment: En mi opinion tienes 2 opciones,
la 1ra es instanciar tu clase Lista en el Main y pasarlas por referencias a ambos frames
la 2 opcion es instanciar tu clase lista en una clase que tenga implementado el patron Singleton

Answer (score 1):

Porque no creas una instancia de `Lista` y la pasas como argumento a las instancias de las clases `Menu`. De esta manera en todos los objetos `Menu` estarás trabajando con la misma referencia de la lista.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lista lista = new Lista();

    Menu1 m1 = new Menu1(lista);
    Menu2 m2 = new Menu2(lista);

    // ...

}
```

Recuerda recibir el objeto de la lista en el constructor de los objetos `Menu`.

Menu1

```
public class Menu1 {

    Listas lista;

    public Menu1(Lista lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Menu2

```
public class Menu2 {

    Listas lista;

    public Menu2(Lista lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres que Menu1 pueda accesar la lista del Menu2, ¿porque no agregar un método que la proporcione?

```
public class Menu2 {
    Listas listas;

public Listas dameLista() { return listas;}
/etc
}
```

Entonces en Menu1 puedes agregar un método que despliegue la lista:

```
public class Menu1 {

    public void recorrido(Listas lista) { listas.recorrer();}
///etc
}
```

Y en tu clase Menu:

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu1 m1 = new Menu1();
        Menu2 m2 = new Menu2();

        m2.Llenado();
        m1.Recorrido(m2.dameLista());

    }
 }
```

Comment: Intenté de forma textual, pero ésto no me funcionó. En su momento creí que podría funcionar pero no entiendo el por qué

Comment: Jorge, si te refieres al ejemplo que puse, no era para que lo copiaras. Era para que vieras como hacerlo. Creo que es importante que entiendas la lógica del esquema que propongo antes de meterlo en tu código.

Comment: Si entendí la lógica. de hecho como te mencioné, lo había pensado. Pero aún así no me funcionó, otras personas me dicen que deje el ArrayList en static y tomará siempre el mismo valor

Comment: si puedes poner como quedaron tus clases ayudaría a entender el problema.